# How to Save Calls using Skype API

Tags: c#, skype

I am currently trying to develop an application which uses Skype API to call or send text messages to either phone number or p2p client.

So the problem is : I wanna save the speakings during calls and when I call someone I wanna put a wav file in front of the phone like a robot speaking.

So How can I do that ? I explored tons of documentation but they actually couldn't help me  in the way I want.

There are command objects and other classes,Pff I am really confused.

Some one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay actually instead of asking my skype api problem here, I should have asked them in Skype API developer forums. Because it's the best way to get an answer :)

try this web site : [Skype Public API Forums](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?s=7350047430f31d302ef8811af1451272&showforum=16)

Hope it helps.